# Hex String to Bytes (NSData)

Tags: swift, serialization

I'm trying to convert this Objective-C code (originally found in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511588/2415822)) which turns an `NSString` into `NSData` to Swift:

> ```
> - (NSData *)dataFromHexString {
>     const char *chars = [self UTF8String];
>     int i = 0, len = self.length;
>
>     NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:len / 2];
>     char byteChars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
>     unsigned long wholeByte;
>
>     while (i < len) {
>         byteChars[0] = chars[i++];
>         byteChars[1] = chars[i++];
>         wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, NULL, 16);
>         [data appendBytes:&wholeByte length:1];
>     }
>
>     return data;
> }
> ```

My first pass looked like this:

```
func hexStringToBytes(hexString: String) -> NSData? {
    guard let chars = hexString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { return nil}
    var i = 0
    let length = hexString.characters.count

    let data = NSMutableData(capacity: length/2)
    var byteChars: [CChar] = [0, 0, 0]

    var wholeByte = CUnsignedLong()

    while i < length {
        byteChars[0] = chars[i++]
        byteChars[1] = chars[i++]
        i+=1
        wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, nil, 16)
        data?.appendBytes(&wholeByte, length: 1)
    }

    return data
}
```

I realized I could optimize this further, since `++` is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3:

```
func hexStringToBytes(hexString: String) -> NSData? {
    guard let chars = hexString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { return nil}
    var i = 0
    let length = hexString.characters.count

    let data = NSMutableData(capacity: length/2)
    var byteChars: [CChar] = [0, 0, 0]

    var wholeByte: CUnsignedLong = 0

    while i < length {
        byteChars[0] = chars[i]
        i+=1
        byteChars[1] = chars[i]
        i+=1
        wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, nil, 16)
        data?.appendBytes(&wholeByte, length: 1)
    }

    return data
}
```

And then as an extension on String:

```
extension String {

    func dataFromHexString() -> NSData? {
        guard let chars = cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { return nil}
        var i = 0
        let length = characters.count

        let data = NSMutableData(capacity: length/2)
        var byteChars: [CChar] = [0, 0, 0]

        var wholeByte: CUnsignedLong = 0

        while i < length {
            byteChars[0] = chars[i]
            i+=1
            byteChars[1] = chars[i]
            i+=1
            wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, nil, 16)
            data?.appendBytes(&wholeByte, length: 1)
        }

        return data
    }
}
```

A few questions:

1. How can I optimize the ugly `i+=1` lines?
2. Is `cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)` the correct way to get the `[CChar]` from the string?
3. Since this is almost a direct translation from Objective-C, is there any way to make this more "Swifty," say by using `map` or `stride`, without sacrificing speed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that your code does not detect invalid input data.
For example, the string `"XX"` is just converted to a zero byte.
Detecting invalid input with `strtoul()` is a bit tricky, there is an
alternative suggestion below.

---

```
let data = NSMutableData(capacity: length/2)
```

creates an optional `NSData`. If that fails then the optional chaining

```
data?.appendBytes(&wholeByte, length: 1)
```

simply does nothing, i.e. the error is ignored. Better check the 
success immediately:

```
guard let data = NSMutableData(capacity: length/2) else { return nil }
```

---

> How can I optimize the ugly `i+=1` lines?

By using `stride`:

```
func dataFromHexString() -> NSData? {
    guard let chars = cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { return nil}
    let length = characters.count

    guard let data = NSMutableData(capacity: length/2) else { return nil }
    var byteChars: [CChar] = [0, 0, 0]
    var wholeByte: CUnsignedLong = 0

    for i in 0.stride(to: length, by: 2) {
        byteChars[0] = chars[i]
        byteChars[1] = chars[i + 1]
        wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, nil, 16)
        data.appendBytes(&wholeByte, length: 1)
    }

    return data
}
```

This does not change the performance. The time to convert a 512,000
character string is 0.0140 sec on my computer (test code at the end).

---

> Is `cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)` the correct way to get the `[CChar]` from the string?

That is fine as far as I can see. There is also

```
self.withCString {
    // $0 is a pointer to the NUL-terminated UTF-8 string
}
```

which I personally prefer, but I could not detect a difference in
the performance.

---

> Since this is almost a direct translation from Objective-C, is there any way to make this more "Swifty," say by using `map` or `stride`, without sacrificing speed?

`stride()` is already used for the iteration. I do not see an use-case
for `map()` here.

But the performance can be improved considerably.
As observed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38478888/1187415)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26990394/1187415), accessing the *UTF-16 view*
of a Swift string is very fast. This leads to the following implementation:

```
func dataFromHexString() -> NSData? {

    let utf16 = self.utf16
    guard let data = NSMutableData(capacity: utf16.count/2) else { return nil }

    var byteChars: [CChar] = [0, 0, 0]
    var wholeByte: CUnsignedLong = 0
    var i = utf16.startIndex
    while i != utf16.endIndex {
        byteChars[0] = CChar(truncatingBitPattern: utf16[i])
        byteChars[1] = CChar(truncatingBitPattern: utf16[i.advancedBy(1, limit: utf16.endIndex)])
        wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, nil, 16)
        data.appendBytes(&wholeByte, length: 1)
        i = i.advancedBy(2, limit: utf16.endIndex)
    }
    return data
}
```

which converts the 512,000 character string in 0.00185 sec.
Note that invalid input is still not detected.

We can still make it faster by converting the UTF-16 code points
"manually" instead of using `strtoul()`. This is more code,
but again faster, and also detects all kinds of invalid input:

```
func dataFromHexString() -> NSData? {

    // Convert 0 ... 9, a ... f, A ...F to their decimal value,
    // return nil for all other input characters
    func decodeNibble(u: UInt16) -> UInt8? {
        switch(u) {
        case 0x30 ... 0x39:
            return UInt8(u - 0x30)
        case 0x41 ... 0x46:
            return UInt8(u - 0x41 + 10)
        case 0x61 ... 0x66:
            return UInt8(u - 0x61 + 10)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    let utf16 = self.utf16
    guard let data = NSMutableData(capacity: utf16.count/2) else {
        return nil
    }

    var i = utf16.startIndex
    while i != utf16.endIndex {
        guard let
            hi = decodeNibble(utf16[i]),
            lo = decodeNibble(utf16[i.advancedBy(1, limit: utf16.endIndex)])
        else {
                return nil
        }
        var value = hi << 4 + lo
        data.appendBytes(&value, length: 1)
        i = i.advancedBy(2, limit: utf16.endIndex)
    }
    return data
}
```

The time to convert the 512,000 character string is now
0.0008 seconds. This is more than 17 times faster than the original code.

---

**Test code:**

```
let s1 = (0 ... 255).map { String(format:"%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")
let str = Repeat(count: 100, repeatedValue: s1).joinWithSeparator("")
print(str.characters.count) // 51200

let start = NSDate()
if let data = str.dataFromHexString() {
    let duration = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(start)
    print(duration)
} else {
    print("failed")
}
```

The tests were done on a MacBook, with the program compiled in
Release mode.

Comment: Exceptional as usual, thanks Martin.  I hadn't even considered doing the manual nibble decoding.

Comment: Hey Martin, do you know what the Swift 3 equivalent is for `advancedBy(:limit:)`?

Comment: @JAL: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38520170/1187415 for an example.

Comment: @JAL: An improved version for Swift 3 can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40278391/1187415.